# VBA Windows Activate fails for different file version

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file generated from an ASPX page that opens in a PROTECTED VIEW. I wish to write some Excel 2013 VBA to format the Excel 97 file and save it.

```
Windows("DS – Incidents and Linked Problems.xls").Activate
Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
```

gives error 9 subscript out of range.
I would ideally want to access this file as it is opened as the file and browser versions are set and would be very difficult to change.

Edit:
To help me see what's going on I ran:

```
Debug.Print Workbooks.Count  
For Each w In Workbooks  
    Debug.Print w.Name  
Next
```

giving

> 1
>   Book1.xlsm

I then used `Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit` on the second file and ran the same code which returned:

> 2
>   Book1.xlsm
>   DS – Incidents and Linked Problems.xls

Comment: Maybe try `Workbooks("filename.xls")`

Comment: Thanks @Davesexel. I tried **Workbooks** instead of **Windows** and it a gives the same error. If I use `Debug.Print Filename` from the file itself it returns a blank line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found [ProtectedViewWindow Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/protectedviewwindow-object-excel) and using the information found there was able to come up with:

```
If Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
    For pvwi = 1 To Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count
        If Application.ProtectedViewWindows(pvwi).SourceName = "DS – Incidents and Linked Problems.xls" Then
               Application.ProtectedViewWindows(pvwi).Activate
        End If
        DoEvents
    Next
End If
Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
```